# vcredist_x86.exe for VS11

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We just migrated our code from MSVS9 to MSVS11.

I want to install the C++ runtimes manually with the help of vcredist_x86.exe but can't find the file for VisualStudio 11. Any pointers on where can I find vcredist_x86.exe for VS11?

I was able to compile the code correctly on my system which has VS11 Beta Ultimate installed. I did include the new MSCRT.lib while compiling the code.

When I try to run the code on a different system, I get an error -"Missing MSVCR110.dll". I can hack this file to be in the binaries of my application, then it asks for "MSVCP110.dll". I understood by reading some blogs that hacking this file wouldn't work for systems below Windows7.

Comment: I was able to grab it from the installed folder on my system -
\\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86